# Using sharedPreferences like a variable in my text

Tags: flutter, dart

How to use sharedPreferences data in my `Text` widget?

saving sP:

```
sharedPreferences.setString("firstName", jsonResponse['firstName']);
sharedPreferences.setString("lastName", jsonResponse['lastName']);
```

reading sP:

```
  getUserDetails(String key) async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final firstName = sharedPreferences.getString('firstName') ?? '';
    final lastName = sharedPreferences.getString('lastName') ?? '';
    print(firstName);
    print(lastName);
  }
```

but how to use my `firstName` and `lastName` like a text variable?

i try in this way:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Code Land", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              sharedPreferences.clear();
              // sharedPreferences.commit();
              Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginPage()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
            },
            child: Text("Log Out", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(child: Text(getUserDetails('firstName'))), <=== HERE
      drawer: Drawer(),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can't do that directly, because the sharedPreferences instance needs to be `awaited` for.
But there is a Widget called `FutureBuilder` with that widget you could do something like:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<SharedPreferences>(
      future: SharedPreferences.getInstance(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData)
          return Scaffold(
            body: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ); //Just some placeholder loading widget
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Code Land", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  snapshot.data.clear(); //Note instead of sharedPreferences we now use snapshot.data
                  Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginPage()),
                      (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
                },
                child: Text("Log Out", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          body: Center(child: Text(getUserDetails('firstName', snapshot.data))), 
//Here you just pass the already loaded sharedPreferences to your method and make the method return your result immediately instead of a Future 
          drawer: Drawer(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: thanks, i paste your code and console throw me ```type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'```

Comment: i think taht i cant use this because i'cant paste ```snapshot.data``` in ```getUserDetails('firstName', snapshot.data)```

Comment: can you show how to edit ```getUserDetails()``` function?

Comment: I think ```String getUserDetails(String key, SharedPreferences prefs){
  return prefs.getString(key) ?? '';
}``` is what you are looking for.

Comment: still this same error ```type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'```:(

Comment: i don't have idea what is can be, i sit behind this for a few hours and still this same...

Comment: could you tell me the line where this exception is thrown?

Comment: ```The relevant error-causing widget was
    FutureBuilder<SharedPreferences> ``` === ```return FutureBuilder<SharedPreferences>```

Comment: Sadly I can't reproduce your error with the code you provided, would you mind providing more code?